# Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (*) to 'NSDictionary' (*)

Tags: swift, flutter, dart

I am currently trying to get more experience in dart/flutter in connection with websockets and am now facing a problem. Maybe someone can give me a tip

Im trying to send:

```
send('checkRoom', {"type": "checkRoom", "room": roomName});
```

```
  send(event, data) {
    data['type'] = event;
    JsonEncoder encoder = new JsonEncoder();
    socket.emit('message', [encoder.convert(data)]);
  }
```

```
            case "emit":
                let eventName: String = arguments["eventName"] as! String
                **let data: [Any] = arguments["arguments"] as! [Any]**
                let reqId: String? = arguments["reqId"] as? String
                self.log("emitting:::", data, ":::to:::", eventName);
                if (reqId == nil) {
                    socket.emit(eventName, with: data)
                } else {
                    socket.emitWithAck(eventName, with: data).timingOut(after: 0) { data in 
                        self.channel.invokeMethod("incomingAck", arguments: [
                            "args": data,
                            "reqId": reqId
                        ]);
                    }
                }
                result(nil)
```

(https://github.com/infitio/flutter_socket_io/blob/035d56d941037194a5f042a0a3f399c42eb20e5d/ios/Classes/AdharaSocket.swift#L76)

and it stucks on

```
let data: [Any] = arguments["arguments"] as! [Any]
```

with error message:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (*) to 'NSDictionary' (*).
```

edit:
as requested the full log

```
2021-03-04 21:58:08.258957+0100 Runner[905:137746] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Socket connected
2021-03-04 21:58:08.259044+0100 Runner[905:137746] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connected, 3]
2021-03-04 21:58:08.259107+0100 Runner[905:137746] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: connect with data: ["/"]
2021-03-04 21:58:08.259130+0100 Runner[905:137938] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://192.168.178.49:8081/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=w2CS4YplpirAWH6GAAAR
["incoming:::", "connect", ["/"], <SocketIO.SocketAckEmitter: 0x280cf1100>]
2021-03-04 21:58:08.259479+0100 Runner[905:137746] LOG SocketParser: Parsing 0
2021-03-04 21:58:08.259592+0100 Runner[905:137746] LOG SocketParser: Decoded packet as: SocketPacket {type: 0; data: []; id: -1; placeholders: 0; nsp: /}
2021-03-04 21:58:08.259877+0100 Runner[905:137938] LOG SocketEngine: Writing poll:  has data: false
2021-03-04 21:58:08.260044+0100 Runner[905:137938] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll:  as type: 2
2021-03-04 21:58:08.260480+0100 Runner[905:137938] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 1:2
2021-03-04 21:58:08.260710+0100 Runner[905:137938] LOG SocketEnginePolling: POSTing
2021-03-04 21:58:08.260781+0100 Runner[905:137938] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling POST http://192.168.178.49:8081/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=w2CS4YplpirAWH6GAAAR
2021-03-04 21:58:08.266167+0100 Runner[905:137746] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: websocketUpgrade with data: [["connection": "Upgrade", "sec-websocket-accept": "qmxHc7JKkY/2ynzmr2AY6uUd1+U=", "upgrade": "websocket"]]
2021-03-04 21:58:08.266638+0100 Runner[905:137941] LOG SocketEngineWebSocket: Sending ws: probe as type: 2
2021-03-04 21:58:08.268580+0100 Runner[905:137944] flutter: connected... from the socket manager class
2021-03-04 21:58:08.268646+0100 Runner[905:137944] flutter: /
2021-03-04 21:58:08.268929+0100 Runner[905:137944] flutter: onOpen
2021-03-04 21:58:08.269146+0100 Runner[905:137944] flutter: =================>Open Connection State
2021-03-04 21:58:08.269419+0100 Runner[905:137944] flutter: You are checking the room is empty or not
2021-03-04 21:58:08.269696+0100 Runner[905:137944] flutter: {"type":"checkRoom","room":"test"}
2021-03-04 21:58:08.270270+0100 Runner[905:137941] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 3probe
Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x1fcdfd4a0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1fcdfe418).
2021-03-04 21:58:08.270346+0100 Runner[905:137746] Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x1fcdfd4a0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1fcdfe418).
2021-03-04 21:58:08.270386+0100 Runner[905:137944] flutter: /
(lldb)
```

edit2:
[Can't remove the brackets because of List Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P3Zh.png)

Comment: What is the full error message with stack trace and all?

Comment: @Abion47 i have updated the question